# How to setup Swashbuckle.AspNetCore and Oauth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I'm trying to figure out where I went wrong.

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "MySite API", Version = "v1" });
    options.OperationFilter<AuthorizeCheckOperationFilter>();
    options.OperationFilter<AddSwaggerHeadersOperationFilter>();
    options.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OAuth2Scheme
    {
        Type = "oauth2",
        Flow = "implicit",
        AuthorizationUrl = "authorization url",
        TokenUrl = "token url",
        Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            { "scope", "Scope" }
        }
    });
});


//Configure Method
app.UseSwagger();

app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "MySite API V1");
    options.OAuthClientId("MyClientId");
    options.OAuthAppName("Swagger Api Calls");
    //c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
});

//AuthorizeCheckOperationFilter
internal class AuthorizeCheckOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context.ApiDescription.TryGetMethodInfo(out var methodInfo))
        {
            var attributes = methodInfo.DeclaringType.GetTypeInfo().GetCustomAttributes(true);
            if (attributes.OfType<AuthorizeAttribute>().Any())
            {
                operation.Responses.Add("401", new Response { Description = "Unauthorized" });
                operation.Responses.Add("403", new Response { Description = "Forbidden" });

                operation.Security = new List<IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>>();
                operation.Security.Add(new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
                {
                    { "oauth2", new [] { "api1" } }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}

//Extra field
internal class AddSwaggerHeadersOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (operation.Parameters == null)
            operation.Parameters = new List<IParameter>();

        operation.Parameters.Add(new NonBodyParameter
        {
            Name = "SomeField",
            In = "header",
            Type = "string",
            Required = true,
            Default = "some value"
        });
    }
}
```

Now when I open up the swagger page I get the Authorize button, to which I click and when I fill out the details there I get redirected to my Identity Website which logs me in and redirects right back to swagger. Swagger then says authorized, as if everything is fine.

Then I try to use an API which requires Bearer token to be passed and it doesn't pass it. I don't see it in the header and by my logs from the identity website nothing was passed.

Any idea why or how to fix this? I'm using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 4.1 package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `DocumentFilter` :

```
public class SecurityRequirementsDocumentFilter : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(SwaggerDocument document, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        document.Security = new List<IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>>()
        {
            new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>()
            {
                { "oauth2", new string[]{ "openid", "profile", "email" } },
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And then register the filter in `AddSwaggerGen` function :

```
options.DocumentFilter<SecurityRequirementsDocumentFilter>();
```

Reference : https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/603#issuecomment-368487641

I test with your code sample and it works as expected :

[image]

Comment: This has worked. See I thought my operation filter was suppose to do this. Should I move my logic from operation filter to document?